# Import a single CSV file into multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

I would like to import a single CSV with 7 columns into 2 tables in MySQL.

Columns 1, 2 and 3 go into a single row in table1. Columns 4 and 5 go as a row in table2. Columns 6 and 7 go as a row again in same table2.

How can this be done using PHP or mysql directly?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Could you try rephrasing it?

Comment: You can use the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command in MySQL, and instruct the command to select specific columns for specific tables. You can also instruct the command to link the imported data using foreign keys. Here's an article detailing the specifics: https://blog.terresquall.com/2022/05/splitting-csv-file-into-multiple-mysql-tables/

Answer (score 0):

First fetch all values from csv and store it in an array. Then maintain your array as per your requirement and then start looping and inserting.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        $efected = 0;
        $file_temp = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        
        $handle = fopen($file_temp, "r"); // opening CSV file for reading
        
        if ($handle) { // if file successfully opened
            $i=0;
            while (($CSVrecord = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) { // iterating through each line of our CSV
            
                if($i>0)
                {
                    
                    list($name, $gender, $website, $category, $email, $subcat) = explode(',', $CSVrecord); // exploding CSV record (line) to the variables (fields)
                    //print_r($subcat); sub_cat_ids
                    
                    if($email!='')
                    {
                    
                        $chk_sql = "select * from employees where employee_email='".$email."'";
                        $chk_qry = mysqli_query($conn, $chk_sql);
                        $chk_num_row = mysqli_num_rows($chk_qry);
                        
                        $cat_array = array(trim($category));
                        $subcat_array = explode( ';', $subcat );
                        if(count($subcat_array)>0)
                        {
                            $subcat_array_new = array();
                            foreach($subcat_array as $key => $val)
                            {
                                $subcat_array_new[] = trim($val);
                            }
                        }
                        
                        $cat_sub_cat_merge = array_merge($cat_array, $subcat_array_new);
                        $cat_subcat_comma = implode( "','", $cat_sub_cat_merge );
                        
                        foreach($cat_array as $cat_key => $cat_val)
                        {
                            $chk_cat_sql = "select * from employee_cats where cats_name = '".$cat_val."'";
                            $chk_cat_qry = mysqli_query($conn, $chk_cat_sql);
                            $chk_cat_num_row = mysqli_num_rows($chk_cat_qry);
                            //$all_cat_array = array();
                            if($chk_cat_num_row == 0)
                            {
                                $new_cat_ins = "insert into employee_cats set cats_name = '".$cat_val."', parent_cat_id = '0' ";
                                $new_cat_ins_qry = mysqli_query($conn, $new_cat_ins);
                            }
                        }
                        
                        foreach($subcat_array_new as $subcat_key => $subcat_val)
                        {
                            $chk_subcat_sql = "select * from employee_cats where cats_name = '".$subcat_val."'";
                            $chk_subcat_qry = mysqli_query($conn, $chk_subcat_sql);
                            $chk_subcat_num_row = mysqli_num_rows($chk_subcat_qry);
                            //$all_cat_array = array();
                            if($chk_subcat_num_row == 0 && trim($subcat_val)!='')
                            {
                                //$category
                                $get_catid_sql = "select * from employee_cats where cats_name = '".trim($category)."'";
                                $chk_catid_qry = mysqli_query($conn, $get_catid_sql);
                                $fetch_cat_info = mysqli_fetch_array($chk_catid_qry);
                                $fetch_cat_id = $fetch_cat_info['cats_id'];
                                $new_subcat_ins = "insert into employee_cats set cats_name = '".$subcat_val."', parent_cat_id = '".$fetch_cat_id."' ";
                                $new_subcat_ins_qry = mysqli_query($conn, $new_subcat_ins);
                            }
                        }
                        
                        
                        $get_cat_sql = "select * from employee_cats where cats_name in ('".$cat_subcat_comma."')";
                        $get_cat_qry = mysqli_query($conn, $get_cat_sql);
                        $get_cat_num_row = mysqli_num_rows($get_cat_qry);
                        
                        $sub_category_ids = array();
                        if($get_cat_num_row>0)
                        {
                            while($fetch_cat_id = mysqli_fetch_array($get_cat_qry))
                            {
                                if($fetch_cat_id['parent_cat_id']==0)
                                {
                                    $category_id = $fetch_cat_id['cats_id'];
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $sub_category_ids[] = $fetch_cat_id['cats_id'];
                                }
                            }
                            
                            $sub_cat_id_vals_comma = implode(",", $sub_category_ids);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $category_id = 0;
                            $sub_cat_id_vals_comma = "";
                        }
                        
                        if($chk_num_row>0)
                        {
                            // and here you can easily compose SQL queries and map you data to the tables you need using simple variables
                            $update_sql = "update employees set 
                                                            employee_name='".$name."', 
                                                            employee_gender='".$gender."', 
                                                            employees_website='".$website."',
                                                            employees_cat_id='".$category_id."',
                                                            sub_cat_ids='".$sub_cat_id_vals_comma."'
                                                            where employee_email='".$email."'";
                            $mysqli_qry = mysqli_query($conn, $update_sql);
                            
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        
                            // and here you can easily compose SQL queries and map you data to the tables you need using simple variables
                            $insert_sql = "insert into employees set 
                                                                    employee_name='".$name."', 
                                                                    employee_gender='".$gender."', 
                                                                    employees_website='".$website."',
                                                                    employees_cat_id='".$category_id."',
                                                                    sub_cat_ids='".$sub_cat_id_vals_comma."',
                                                                    employee_email='".$email."'";
                            $mysqli_qry = mysqli_query($conn, $insert_sql);
                        }
                        
                        $efected = 1;
                    }
                }
            
            $i++;
            }
            fclose($handle); // closing file handler
        }
    
    if($efected==1)
    {
        header('location:'.$site_url.'?import=success');
    }
    else
    {
        header('location:'.$site_url.'?import=failed');
    }

?>
```